# How to modify a JSON value in a file using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have created a drop down menu for people to edit the location. And all contents are generated by for loop, how may i depends on the feedID to change the region, because the `$.post()` funcion would change all region but not depends on it's feedID at the moment.

```
<span class="dropdown">
    <span class="result-date" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Hong Kong
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </span>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
        <li id="CTHK"><a href="">Hong Kong</a></li>
        <li id="CTTW"><a href="">Taiwan</a></li><
        <li id="CTMA"><a href="">Macau</a></li><
        <li id="CTCN"><a href="">China</a></li><
        <li id="CTOT"><a href="">Others</a></li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

After the users have made decision of the modification and click on the desire option, it will trigger a `$.post()` function in order to change the JSON's content via speicifc api

```
var initRegionEdit = function() {

    $("#CTHK").click(function() {

        var api = "/domain/path/somemorepaths?id=" + id;

        var postData = {
            region : "TW"
        };

        $.post(api_submit, postData).done(function (data) {
            console.log(postData)
        }); 
    })
}
```

And afterward it will get into an JSON file and change the region section

```
  "errorCode": null,
  "message": "Success",
  "result": {
    "total": 2,
    "data": [
      {
        "title": "watever",
        "content": " lietlie siktl i's fgkkksfsag...",
        "region": "Hong Kong",
        "feedId": "dfc68cff0a2afc540407d02f554d9508",
      },
      {
        "title": "Visual F",
        "content": "STORE \" I'm ...",
        "region": "Hong Kong",
        "feedId": "e54de354837e3add77b1030e5456e522",
      }
```

how may i depends on the feedID to change the the region?

UPDATE 1:
Let's  assume the user click on **others** ,The outcome I'd like to see is like when the user click on the .section defined by a feedId.

```
<div class="dfc68cff0a2afc540407d02f554d9508"> //generate by {{feedId}} handle bar js
 <span class="dropdown">
        <span class="result-date" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Hong Kong
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </span>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
            <li id="CTHK"><a href="">Hong Kong</a></li>
            <li id="CTTW"><a href="">Taiwan</a></li><
            <li id="CTMA"><a href="">Macau</a></li><
            <li id="CTCN"><a href="">China</a></li><
            <li id="CTOT"><a href="">Others</a></li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</div>
```

and the javascript api should change the feedId match the section instead of every json's region

```
  {
            "title": "Visual F",
            "content": "STORE \" I'm ...",
            "region": "Others",
            "feedId": "e54de354837e3add77b1030e5456e522",
          }
```

> P.S I am developing the application by node.js

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on the following procedure:

Reading file -> modifying its contents -> write file would be to use the [File System Node Module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)

Example code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// Read file and parse into JSON
var jsonFileObject = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('fileName')); 

... modify the contents of jsonFileObject as required

// Write the modified contents back to the file
var jsonFileObject = JSON.parse(fs.writeFileSync('fileName', jsonFileObject));
```

To modify the `region` based on the `feedId` in your particular example:

```
for (var dataIndex in jsonFileObject.result.data) {
   if (jsonFileObject.result.data[dataIndex].feedId === feedId) {
      jsonFileObject.result.data[dataIndex].region = updatedRegion;
   }
}
```

assuming the JSON file has the same format as your post. If not, it should be fairly straightforward to modify the example to meet your needs.

Comment: Is there any example which has more details? because i am not too familiar with this.

Comment: @anson920520 is it more details around how to modify the jsonFileObject or around reading and writing files?

Comment: About how to matching the content. I do know how to do things about data exchange. The point of the question is how to change "specific" region depend on the "specific" feedID matching with the region

Comment: @anson920520 I updated my answer with an example of how you iterate over the data in the JSON object.

Comment: i ll have a try and will update soon, once i fixed this issues i ll accept your answer thanks again

Comment: @anson920520 no worries